# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, exception

I was trying to build my app but it always returns this weird error :-

```
Launching lib\main.dart on M2003J15SC in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> File 'C:\Native\findhelpapp\findhelpapp\build\location\intermediates\annotation_processor_list\debug\annotationProcessors.json' specified for property 'processorListFile' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried to run `flutter clean` and rebuild the project and it doesn't work too :"(

So what should I do to fix this error??

My `flutter doctor` logs :-

```
C:\Native\findhelpapp\findhelpapp>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1082], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

C:\Native\findhelpapp\findhelpapp>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Android SDK and Jdk Location

2.Copy next lines at the end of gradle.properties

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

3. And set the latest version

on file app\build.gradle

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
multiDexEnabled true
```

}

4.And Run your app a
gain

Comment: I think all my files of the project is fine but the problem in the JDK location but how can I check it? Also I added my `flutter doctor` logs to the anwser

Comment: I checked my JDK location and it's fine but the problem is still existing :"(

Comment: Pleas check android SDK location or download latest SDK versions
and in build file add latest targeted SDK 
flutter clean and Run Again